# Use Create Mode Profile - Selection fields shown twice

Tags: profile, joomla

Joomla 3.5.1
Civicrm 4.7.7

I have created a custom profile, used for volunteer registration.
When the form is loaded on the joomla front end in create mode, any fields that are either multiselect, or simply select, show the selections field twice.
First field shows default as "-none-" and the second shows "Select some options".

See here for example: [image: Example]

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a more standard theme?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion A more standard Joomla theme?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Than you! That was the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a theme related issue and if you try a more standard Joomla theme for the civicrm pages then you might find the problem disappears in which case you then know that you need to either switch theme or resolve some css issues.